# A screen protector or not for the retina screen?

Tags: macbook-pro, screen, accessories

Recently, I bought my very first MacBook Pro with Retina Display.

I am hesitating between having a screen protector or not.
Some claim that a protector can prevent the retina display from scratch, while others say that one can only get the best out of the retina display without any extra protection.

Is such a protector worthwhile?

Will the screen get scratched when I use a cloth to clean it, if I do not have the protector?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The points raised are both correct. While having the protector will prevent scratches on the screen, it will also reduce the quality of the display quite significantly. When I bought my Mac, I was also met with this dilemma. After having tried the best screen protector that the Apple Store had, I decided not to go with one. The display doesn't really scratch all that much, and I have not been able to induce a scratch even after using a cheap cloth. 
I would suggest you to use a screen cleaning liquid every time you use a cloth, as that is how I have been able to prevent the scratches.

Comment: Really?  I realize that this is an old question, but I'd like to ask something.  In my experience, it's incredibly easy to get small scratches and dings in the glass of a MacBook Pro with Retina display.  Now, I don't think that a microfiber cloth will scratch it, but if some type of harder dust particles are on the glass, using a microfiber cloth could very well cause problems.  I have a feeling that the glass isn't as durable as the glass on iPhones (and other iOS devices).  What do you think?

Comment: @1dareu2mov3 While I do have scratches on my display, they're only visible with the display turned off, so it's not a problem for me. If you apply a liquid first, it will dislodge the dust particles enough that they don't cause excessive damage.

Answer (score 2):

Don't! I have a screen protector on that's impossible to get off. Tried suction with vacuum and screen was coming off. I saw videos where adhesive was so strong that it pulled off polarizer along with the screen protector. I have to live with this protector now and won't be able to see the actual screen's beauty. Sad! Never apply screen protector on a laptop. They are really not required.

Answer (score 1):

Screens of the current models and nearly all modern MacBooks / MBPs are covered with a sheet of glass.  Your not going to scratch it while wiping it with a clean cloth.  Where previous models, primarily the ones that came with the anti-glare displays where much more susceptible to scratching.  If this were an iPhone or an iPad I would consider a screen protector, but on a Macbook the only time the screen is vulnerable to damage is while your working on it, I don't expect you will store it in a bag etc, while open.

Answer (score 1):

I always think your better off with a screen protector. I have a screen protector on mine and I'm not dying over the difference. Do your research, invest the money and get quality stuff. If you get a cheap one then you'll dramatically reduce the display. Spend some good money and you won't have to give up performance for protection. Or scratch your display and replace it vs replacing a 40$ screen protector. Doesn't matter how easy or hard it is to scratch the display. Bottom line is... it can be done so prevent it.

Answer (score 1):

One year after buying a brand new MacBook Pro pro I got a small scratch in the centre of the screen - it was like scratching sunglasses right in the centre - was super annoying - luckily the Apple Store agreed to replace the Retina display at no cost - I then got a cheap screen guard since then - you cannot tell the difference.

But I have just bought a 2018 MacBook Pro and I've installed 2x screen guards and both give some sort of vertical strobing effect - not sure why it's happening - it's annoying - I'll keep it on till I find one that doesn't strobe.

Answer (score 0):

I think that there has to be some degradation of the retina display when you use any screen protector. That did not prevent me from using one on my iPad 4 with the retina display - because I do use one. I prefer having the protection for my screen to the very slight loss of quality that the screen protector may cause. But Providing its of a good quality i would leave it on. The amount of people I've come across both with phones and tablets how have put a small scratch on the screen and to my surprise they have done it using a good quality cleaning cloth that has had a small speck of grit or something like that have left them with a small scratch.

Answer (score 0):

WARNING!! I used to usually clean with liquid but after 2 years my display got staingate problem and later I found out apple actually suggest to use only their cloth to clean

Answer (score 0):

The Moshi protector: don't buy!
I removed the Moshi after 5 years and screen got irrepairable damaged. Staingate all over the screen.

Answer (score -1):

Why not? I think it's better to be safe than sorry a screen protector of good quality is a safeguard and believe me the moshI protector is awesome expensive but awesome do not get a cheap one that leaves tonnes of bubbles moshI is the only protector I'd use or nothing at all ,but if you care for your Mac retina than you shouldn't have an issue for scratches in the first place ,never wip before blowing the dust 2, liquid screen cleaner and 3 a very soft screen cloth that's used for camera lenses then I'd say you don't need a screen protector if you follow those steps .cheers.pick your poison and you don't lose quality of the retina that's noticeable that's well over exaggerated trust me the quality is the same.

Answer (score -2):

No .Macbooks or even ipad when protected in a case do not require screen protectors. I have my ipad with retina naked for 2 yrs straight without developing a single scratch.But it also depends on how much care u take of your device.